# Why do scientists measure fundamental constants so precisely?

Tags: electrons, measurements, electrical-engineering

According to the last CODATA report the charge of electron is measured very precisely (10 decimal places). And it's not only about the charge of electron. 
Why do scientists measure fundamental constants so precisely? I mean, do we really need such accuracy in engineering and electronics? Can you give examples, where such accuracy is important?

Comment: "*Why do scientists measure fundamental constants so precisely?*" because they can, of course. "*Can you give examples, where such accuracy is important?*" yes: for example, we need a lot of precision when measuring the [magnetic moment of the muon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomalous_magnetic_dipole_moment#Muon), because this number is very closely related to [physics beyond the Standard Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_beyond_the_Standard_Model).

Comment: Precision measurements are precision tests. Consider the role that the precession of the perihelion of Mercury played in the supporting general relativity.

Comment: As for practical uses of these precision measurements, consider the fact that GPS only works because we understand general relativity.

Comment: *"Can you give examples, where such accuracy is important?"* - the measurement proposal results in a grant?

Answer (score 1):

Physics is about making models of the world, if you can make them as accurate as possible why wouldn't you? Incidentally, sometimes you really need acuracy as the smallest difference in your initial conditions can make a great difference in your outcome (see chaotic systems, the best example is weather or the double pendulum)

Imagine instead of taking g=9.81... we took g=10, he outcome in the double pendulum would be very different. We would have some useless equations that cannot predict anything.